# How to get listbox all values in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, listbox

How to get listbox all values in jquery ?

i have 
HTML code like this

```
<div class="right" style="width: 300px">
<fieldset class="field_set">
    <legend>Add Area</legend>
    <select id="addArea-list" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px"></select>
    <br/> <a href="#" id="addArea">Add Multiple Areas</a>

</fieldset>
```

i'm adding listbox values in button click in jquery like below

```
     var value = $("#Area_name").val(); // value added 
     $("#addArea-list").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(value));
```

How to get listbox all values in jquery .

i have tried following but i get it all values append returns single value

```
    var floors = [];
$("#addArea-list").each(function () {
    debugger;
    floors.push({
        FloorName: $(this).text()
    });
});
```

if my list box have following vales means text1 , text2 , text3

it returns text1text2text3   ... how to get each values ?

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's `map()`, which will iterate through the matches and push to jQuery collection the value returned from the function. Convert the jQuery object returned into a standard Array using `.get()`:

```
var floors = $("#addArea-list option").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4LFR/)